# Time Complexity quick sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o, quicksort

I am learning about time complexity recently. As I trying to find the Big O of quicksort, I saw on the Internet saying quicksort has an O(n log n) for Best-case performance and O(n^2) for Worst-case performance. From what I have understood, Big O notation describes the upper bound limit of an algorithm, and it states its worst-case performance. Why is there saying "quicksort has an O(n log n) for Best-case performance"? I thought Big O is used to describe the worst-case performance.

Comment: Big O is just used to relate runtime (or space) to the size of the input. It makes sense to talk about it in the best, average, and worst case. The overall bound on the algorithm is, of course, the worst case because that subsumes the best and average cases.

Comment: Big O describes an upper bound on a function, not an algorithm. It's a common misconception that Big O has something to do with "worst case". It doesn't. You can use it to describe an upper bound on the worst-case (or the best case, or the average case) beahviour, or to describe something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the worst-case performance rarely occurs in QuickSort - you have to be really unlucky to partition your input so that your pivot is always your smallest or largest element in that input.

Since the average-case performance, which is equal to the best-case, happens most of the time, people choose to mention that instead or both. I think that many programming languages with built-in sorting functions have implemented QuickSort for their function (but not for every type of input). That shows how strong this algorithm is.

You may also find this article useful: [Analysis of quicksort](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/quick-sort/a/analysis-of-quicksort)